# Why is MacBook pro 2018 magnetic on the back?

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm just wondering why the back of my MacBook Pro 2018 and, in general, all the backs of newest MBPs are magnetic (i.e., left and right sides under the pad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MacBooks use magnets to detect whether they are open or closed (and trigger the according actions like going to sleep/clamshell mode, etc.) and to magnetically keep the MacBook shut.

Comment: Do you gave a canorical source of this information?

Comment: While Apple doesn't seem to share any information on the mechanism, you can find some information on this in "teardowns" as performed by companies like iFixIt and you can test it yourself by holding a magnet (an iPad Smart Cover for example - which essentially uses the same mechanism for automatic locking on iPadOS) to the corresponding space on your MacBook (position can vary by model).

Comment: @user3439894: You can open the [Apple Technical Guide for MacBook Pro (17-inch, Mid 2010)](https://tim.id.au/laptops/apple/macbook/mbp17_mid10.pdf) and search for "magnetic sleep sensor" to confirm magnets are used in older MacBook Pro models.

Comment: @David Anderson, Thanks. It's not that I didn't believe the original answer, I just like to see something to backup brief answers.